# How can i test text color of an element by nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, nightwatch.js, automation-testing, nightwatch

whenever I enter more than >140 it is text getting red color. I want to verify text color getting is red or not.

[image: Find the referral html]

My HTML element like this

```
<input placeholder="Systolic" type="text" class="form-control" value="150">
```

css selector: `#root > div > main > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(2) > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.row.mt-4 > div > div.carenotebox > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div.ml-2.carenote-textbox-holder.labOutOfRange > div > input`

I tried enter text 150 and checked is it changed red color or not by using below mention way but it is not working.

`browser.expect.element('#root > div > main > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(2) > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.row.mt-4 > div > div.carenotebox > div > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > div.ml-2.carenote-textbox-holder.labOutOfRange > div > input').to.have.css('color').which.equals('red')`

Comment: You cannot use `[placeholder=Systolic]` as selector?

Comment: Your `input` is clearly not the direct child of the 2nd div.

Comment: I am not use [placeholder=Systolic] as selector . i am using above css selector only